# Multiple errors Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013

Tags: crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I have many errors in Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013 on my Account entities,when creating,updating or saving records, I can't reproduce these errors, they just occurs sometimes, always on different actions, all my javascript is ok, I use IE 11, if anyone have an idea how to mention that problem,please help me
Here is example of error:

```
<CrmScriptErrorReport>
  <ReportVersion>1.0</ReportVersion>
  <ScriptErrorDetails>
   <Message>Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference</Message>
   <Line>5</Line>
   <URL>/_common/global.ashx?ver=583652583</URL>
   <PageURL>/main.aspx?etc=3&extraqs=%3fetc%3d3%26id%3ddf2e1105-0208-e411-b50b-d89d676450ec&pagemode=iframe&pagetype=entityrecord</PageURL>
   <Function>anonymous(a,b){a[a.length]=b}</Function>
   <CallStack>
    <Function>anonymous(a,b){a[a.length]=b}</Function>
   </CallStack>
  </ScriptErrorDetails>
</CrmScriptErrorReport>
```

Comment: How confident are you in your statement that "all my javascript is ok"?  I don't get these errors on an OOB account entity in a clean org.  I'd suggest removing your webresources from the form and verifying the issue is still there.  I'm guessing it won't be.

Comment: these errors can occur even on entities that don't have scripts in web resources.The biggest problem is, that i can't reproduce those errors, so i can't find out if it's fixed or not,I just hope someone maybe had same issue and can help me somehow.

Comment: If you don't have any script resources on the form or in the command bar or sitemap then it would be a script error within the CRM libraries themselves.  However, errors in custom scripts often appear to originate from within the framework itself depending on how far the exception bubbled up the stack.  The only way you'll get them fixed if they are in the framework is to ensure you're on the latest rollup or failing that raise the issue with Microsoft either directly if you're a partner or via connect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use firefox or chrome. Also, if this is bothering your users, you can always ask your system admin or install Global Settings editor extension to your crm instance, and disable all error sending to MS. This can reduce the annoyances of MS CRM in IE.

http://crm2011usersettings.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CRM2011%20User%20Settings%20Utility%20%202.0

**FYI - I do not own the code. Install at your own risk. We have used it in our environment and works like a charm.**